# Access 2000 data type conversion error or seeking correct syntax

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2000

SQL stmt:

```
SELECT TOP 5 col1, col2, Format(col3with$text,"#,##0.00") AS Expr1
FROM myTBL
```

produces results as expected

but
SQL stmt:

```
SELECT TOP 5 col1, col2, Format(col3with$text,"#,##0.00") AS Expr1
FROM myTBL
WEHRE Format(col3with$text,"#,##0.00") > 0
```

produced syntax error

what's the correct syntax?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1 - It's `WHERE`, not `WEHRE`.

2 - `Format()` returns a string, you can't compare this with `> 0`.

Converting to Currency is probably better:

```
WHERE CCur([col3with$text]) > 0
```

3 - `SELECT TOP 5` makes little sense without an ORDER BY clause.